# Appium android hybrid app testing error

Tags: android, selenium, ionic-framework, appium, hybrid

I made an android hybrid app using Ionic 2.Now I want to test it using Appium,Selenium and TestNg. I could able to test native android app successfully but when I'm trying to test hybrid apps, It gives me the following error. My chrome version in both pc and the android device is up-to date.

**Here is the code:**

```
import io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;

// Llibrary for Appium drivers
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;

// Library to create the path to APK
import java.io.File;

// Library used to verify if URL is malformed
import java.net.MalformedURLException;

// Library used to create URL for the Appium server
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

// Libraries for configuring Desired Capabilities
import io.appium.java_client.remote.MobileCapabilityType;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.Capabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.CapabilityType;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class StartApplication {

    public AppiumDriver<WebElement> driver;

    @BeforeTest
    public void setUp() throws MalformedURLException{
        DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
        //capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.AUTOMATION_NAME, "Selendroid");
        cap.setCapability("deviceName","AVY9KA96C0700245");
        cap.setCapability("platformVersion","5.1");
        cap.setCapability("platformName","Android");

        cap.setCapability("appPackage", "com.ionicframework.tbag290562"); //Replace with your app's package
        cap.setCapability("appWaitPackage","com.ionicframework.tbag290562");
        cap.setCapability("appActivity", ".MainActivity"); //Replace with app's Activity
        cap.setCapability("appWaitActivity",".MainActivity");
        driver = new AndroidDriver<WebElement>(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"),cap);

    }
    @Test(priority = 1)
    public void initiateTest(){
        driver.context("WEBVIEW_com.ionicframework.tbag290562");

        driver.findElementByName("q").sendKeys("test test test");

        driver.findElementByName("btng").click();
    }


}
```

**Error**

```
Sep 28, 2017 5:07:06 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: OSS

io.appium.java_client.NoSuchContextException: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: unknown error: Chrome version must be >= 55.0.2883.0
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.28.455520 (cc17746adff54984afff480136733114c6b3704b),platform=Windows NT 10.0.10240 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 0 milliseconds
Build info: version: '3.5.3', revision: 'a88d25fe6b', time: '2017-08-29T12:42:44.417Z'
System info: host: 'RAMITHA-LAP', ip: '192.168.80.167', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_121'
Driver info: io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver
Capabilities [{appPackage=com.ionicframework.tbag290562, deviceScreenSize=720x1280, networkConnectionEnabled=true, warnings={}, appWaitPackage=com.ionicframework.tbag290562, appWaitActivity=.MainActivity, databaseEnabled=false, deviceName=AVY9KA96C0700245, platform=LINUX, deviceUDID=AVY9KA96C0700245, appActivity=.MainActivity, desired={appPackage=com.ionicframework.tbag290562, appActivity=.MainActivity, platformVersion=5.1, appWaitPackage=com.ionicframework.tbag290562, appWaitActivity=.MainActivity, platformName=Android, deviceName=AVY9KA96C0700245}, platformVersion=5.1, webStorageEnabled=false, locationContextEnabled=false, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, deviceModel=HUAWEI TIT-AL00, deviceManufacturer=HUAWEI, platformName=LINUX}]
Session ID: 6e7233e3-08af-49ef-ba03-88cff6e731a3

    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.context(AppiumDriver.java:216)
    at StartApplication.initiateTest(StartApplication.java:53)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:108)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:661)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:869)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1193)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:126)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:109)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:744)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:602)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:380)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:375)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:340)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:289)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1301)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1226)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1144)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1115)
    at org.testng.IDEARemoteTestNG.run(IDEARemoteTestNG.java:72)
    at org.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter.main(RemoteTestNGStarter.java:123)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: unknown error: Chrome version must be >= 55.0.2883.0
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.28.455520 (cc17746adff54984afff480136733114c6b3704b),platform=Windows NT 10.0.10240 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 0 milliseconds
Build info: version: '3.5.3', revision: 'a88d25fe6b', time: '2017-08-29T12:42:44.417Z'
System info: host: 'RAMITHA-LAP', ip: '192.168.80.167', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_121'
Driver info: io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver
Capabilities [{appPackage=com.ionicframework.tbag290562, deviceScreenSize=720x1280, networkConnectionEnabled=true, warnings={}, appWaitPackage=com.ionicframework.tbag290562, appWaitActivity=.MainActivity, databaseEnabled=false, deviceName=AVY9KA96C0700245, platform=LINUX, deviceUDID=AVY9KA96C0700245, appActivity=.MainActivity, desired={appPackage=com.ionicframework.tbag290562, appActivity=.MainActivity, platformVersion=5.1, appWaitPackage=com.ionicframework.tbag290562, appWaitActivity=.MainActivity, platformName=Android, deviceName=AVY9KA96C0700245}, platformVersion=5.1, webStorageEnabled=false, locationContextEnabled=false, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, deviceModel=HUAWEI TIT-AL00, deviceManufacturer=HUAWEI, platformName=LINUX}]
Session ID: 6e7233e3-08af-49ef-ba03-88cff6e731a3
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:215)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:167)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.JsonHttpResponseCodec.reconstructValue(JsonHttpResponseCodec.java:40)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.AbstractHttpResponseCodec.decode(AbstractHttpResponseCodec.java:82)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.AbstractHttpResponseCodec.decode(AbstractHttpResponseCodec.java:45)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:164)
    at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.execute(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:89)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:646)
    at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.execute(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:42)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.execute(AppiumDriver.java:1)
    at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.execute(AndroidDriver.java:1)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.context(AppiumDriver.java:213)
    ... 25 more


===============================================
Default Suite
Total tests run: 2, Failures: 1, Skips: 0
===============================================


Process finished with exit code 0
```